# JOOQ generator: Missing name

Tags: java, postgresql, gradle, jooq

I'm trying to setup JOOQ with Postgres and Gradle.

Whenever I run the generate task I get ~ 20 `Ambiguous type names`:

> Ambiguous type name      : The object pg_catalog.generate_series
>   generates a type one.dbtest.db.pg_catalog.tables.GenerateSeries which
>   conflicts with the existing type
>   one.dbtest.db.pg_catalog.tables.GenerateSeries on some operating
>   systems. Use a custom generator strategy to disambiguate the types.
>   Ambiguous type name      : The object pg_catalog.generate_series
>   generates a type one.dbtest.db.pg_catalog.tables.GenerateSeries which
>   conflicts with the existing type
>   one.dbtest.db.pg_catalog.tables.GenerateSeries on some operating
>   systems. Use a custom generator strategy to disambiguate the types.

and hundreds of these:

> Missing name             : Object jsonb_exists_all holds a column
>   without a name at position 2 Missing name             : Object
>   jsonb_exists_any holds a column without a name at position 1 Missing
>   name             : Object jsonb_exists_any holds a column without a
>   name at position 2 Missing name             : Object jsonb_ge holds a
>   column without a name at position 1 Missing name             : Object
>   jsonb_ge holds a column without a name at position 2 Missing name
>   : Object jsonb_gt holds a column without a name at position 1 Missing
>   name             : Object jsonb_gt holds a column without a name at
>   position 2 Missing name             : Object jsonb_hash holds a column
>   without a name at position 1 Missing name             : Object
>   jsonb_in holds a column without a name at position 1 Missing name
>   : Object jsonb_le holds a column without a name at position 1 Missing
>   name             : Object jsonb_le holds a column without a name at
>   position 2 Missing name             : Object jsonb_lt holds a column
>   without a name at position 1 Missing name             : Object
>   jsonb_lt holds a column without a name at position 2 Missing name
>   : Object jsonb_ne holds a column without a name at position 1 Missing
>   name             : Object jsonb_ne holds a column without a name at
>   position 2

Do I need to exclude the pg* types?

The generate task is taken from the JOOQ samples:

```
task generate << {
  def writer = new StringWriter()
  def xml = new groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder(writer)
    .configuration("xmlns": "http://www.jooq.org/xsd/jooq-codegen-3.7.0.xsd") {
    jdbc() {
      driver("org.postgresql.Driver")
      url("jdbc:postgresql://localhost/pagila")
      user("xxx")
      password("xxx")
    }
    generator() {
      database() {
        name { mkp.yield( 'org.jooq.util.postgres.PostgresDatabase' ) }
        exclude("pg.*")
      }
      generate() {}
      target() {
        packageName("one.dbtest.db")
        directory("src")
      }
    }
  }

  //println writer.toString()

  org.jooq.util.GenerationTool.main(
    javax.xml.bind.JAXB.unmarshal(
        new StringReader(writer.toString()),
        org.jooq.util.jaxb.Configuration.class
    )
  )
}
```

Updated: DB is pagila from http://pgfoundry.org/projects/dbsamples

Comment: Just so you know, I'm mostly new to Java, Postgres and Gradle :)

Comment: Post the DDL used to generate the POJOs

Comment: DDL? You mean the SQL to generate the DB? I'm testing with pagila from http://pgfoundry.org/projects/dbsamples/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For Postgres you also have to specify the input schema, so it's:

```
generator() {
  database() {
    name { mkp.yield( 'org.jooq.util.postgres.PostgresDatabase' ) }
    inputSchema("public")
  }
[..]
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `<inputSchema>public</inputSchema>` in `<database>` block in your pom.xml file if you have added                            `<name>org.jooq.meta.postgres.PostgresDatabase</name>` in generator.